# Unable to Send data from Server to client on local network in C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, sockets, networking

I need to communicate between two systems on local server. So, I decided to use "Socket" programming in C++. For this I follow [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ucOM0.png) tutorial. I make some changes according to my need like changing port no, IP etc which are working fine. Now the problem is I can send data from Server to Client but I am unable to receive any data from Client to Server.
    **Here is my code for Client:-**

```
int main()
{
    WSADATA wsa;
    SOCKET s;
    struct sockaddr_in server;
    char *message , server_reply[2000];
    int recv_size;

    printf("\nInitialising Winsock...");
    if (WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2,2),&wsa) != 0)
    {
        printf("Failed. Error Code : %d",WSAGetLastError());
        return 1;
    }

    printf("Initialised.\n");

    //Create a socket
    if((s = socket(AF_INET , SOCK_STREAM , 0 )) == INVALID_SOCKET)
    {
        printf("Could not create socket : %d" , WSAGetLastError());
    }

    printf("Socket created.\n");


    server.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("192.168.1.4");
    server.sin_family = AF_INET;
    server.sin_port = htons( 8888 );

    //Connect to remote server
    if (connect(s , (struct sockaddr *)&server , sizeof(server)) < 0)
    {
        puts("connect error");
        return 1;
    }

    puts("Connected");

    if((recv_size = recv(s , server_reply , 2000 , 0)) == SOCKET_ERROR)
    {
        puts("recv failed");
    }
    puts("Reply received\n"); 
     server_reply[recv_size] = '\0';
    puts(server_reply);


    message = "Cleint says:- I am Client";
    if( send(s , message , strlen(message) , 0) < 0)
    {
        puts("Send failed");
        return 1;
    }
   puts("sending data complete\n");
    system("pause");

    return 0;
}
```

**Here is My code for Server:-**

```
int main()
{
    WSADATA wsa;
    SOCKET s , new_socket;
    struct sockaddr_in server , client;
    int c;
      char *message , cleint_reply[2000];
    int recv_size;

    printf("\nInitialising Winsock...");
    if (WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2,2),&wsa) != 0)
    {
        printf("Failed. Error Code : %d",WSAGetLastError());
        return 1;
    }

    printf("Initialised.\n");

    //Create a socket
    if((s = socket(AF_INET , SOCK_STREAM , 0 )) == INVALID_SOCKET)
    {
        printf("Could not create socket : %d" , WSAGetLastError());
    }

    printf("Socket created.\n");

    //Prepare the sockaddr_in structure
    server.sin_family = AF_INET;
    server.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
    server.sin_port = htons( 8888 );

    //Bind
    if( bind(s ,(struct sockaddr *)&server , sizeof(server)) == SOCKET_ERROR)
    {
        printf("Bind failed with error code : %d" , WSAGetLastError());
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    puts("Bind done");

    //Listen to incoming connections
    listen(s , 3);

    //Accept and incoming connection
    puts("Waiting for incoming connections...");

    c = sizeof(struct sockaddr_in);

    while( (new_socket = accept(s , (struct sockaddr *)&client, &c)) != INVALID_SOCKET )
    {
        puts("Connection accepted");

        //Reply to the client
        message = "Server sends:- I am Server\n";

        send(new_socket , message , strlen(message) , 0);
        while(1)
        {
         if((recv_size = recv(s , cleint_reply , 2000 , 0)) == SOCKET_ERROR)
    {
     //  puts("recv failed");
    }
         else
          puts("data received");

    }
    }
    if (new_socket == INVALID_SOCKET)
    {
        printf("accept failed with error code : %d" , WSAGetLastError());
        return 1;
    }

    closesocket(s);
    WSACleanup();

    return 0;
}
```

This is the console messages I am getting on Client:-

- Initialising Winsock...
- Initialised
- Connected
- Server sends:- I am server
- Sending Data complete
- Press any key to continue

And these are the messages I am getting on Server console:-

- Initialising Winsock...
- Socket Created
- Bind Done
- Waiting for incoming connections..
- Connection accepted

  So, please tell we why my server is not able to receive any thing...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the error.

Once you use `accept()` you  have a new file descriptor which you need to use send and receive data [lets say for that specific CLIENT].

> The accept() function shall extract the first connection on the queue of pending connections, create a new socket with the same socket type protocol and address family as the specified socket, and allocate a new file descriptor for that socket.

In your server when you get a new connection you correctly use new file descriptor `recv_size` to send data but you do not use that new connection's file descriptor to receive data.

Wrong code line

```
 if((recv_size = recv(s , cleint_reply , 2000 , 0)) == SOCKET_ERROR)
```

Correction

```
 if((recv_size = recv(new_socket , cleint_reply , 2000 , 0)) == SOCKET_ERROR)
```

this should work now